# Event Viewer Warning: "Installation of the Proof of Purchase from the ACPI table failed. Error code: 0xC004F057"

Tags: windows-server-2012, eventviewer, activation, windows-event-log

I have Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard running on a Dell PowerEdge T320. The server is near one month in use as a domain controller. I've noticed this warning entry showing in the Application log since I first turned it on, even before I performed any changes:

**Installation of the Proof of Purchase from the ACPI table failed. Error code: 0xC004F057**

```
Log Name: Application
Source: Security-SPP
Event ID: 1058
Level: Warning
User: N/A
OpCode: Info
Logged: 9/11/2014 8:42AM
Task Category: None
Keywords: Classic
Computer: (my T320's server & domain name is displayed properly)
```

The warnings appear a couple of times a day, and they began approximately as soon as starting the server for the first time. Even after patching, renaming the computer, & promoting it to domain controller, the warnings persist etc.

Research online suggests that this is related to Windows Activation. However, I have run the SLMGR (SLMGR/xpr) command on the server, and it shows that Windows Server Standard Edition is permanently activated (as expected.) Looks like I'll be calling Dell to see if there is something they can do...

Any thoughts on how to resolve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Dell Enterprise Technical Support (which claimed to have consulted Microsoft engineering) the warning can be disregarded. However, they presented these instructions to eliminate the warnings from continuing to populate on my server.

```
 Using Regedit, traverse to the following location:
 • HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SoftwareProtectionPlatform
 • Add a new DWORD registry named "BiosPkeyOptions" & set the Value Data to "1".
```

This successfully eliminated the warnings from Event Viewer after I was able to reboot the server.

Comment: Dell have added a knowledge base article detailing this issue and the same fix: http://www.dell.com/support/article/al/en/aldhs1/SLN293016/en?c=al&s=dhs&cs=aldhs1&l=en

Answer (score 1):

[Installation of the Proof of Purchase from the ACPI table failed. Error code: 0xC004F057](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN292120/EN)

From the Dell KB: "The solution is to re-register with the product key received when purchasing the server"

Comment: I can say for a fact that in my instance, trying SLMGR (as posted by strict) was attempted (and didn't work) prior to me contacting Dell Enterprise. The solution that Matty Brown & I listed worked for me. I'm actually puzzled why Dell posted that 2nd article a week after they posted the Regedit solution though.

Answer (score 1):

This solution from Dell worked for me.

http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN292120/EN

**slmgr /upk** "Uninstall Product Key"

wait for confirmation window Select **OK**

**slmgr /cpky** "Clear key from Registry"

wait for confirmation windows Select **OK**

**slmgr /rearm**

you will get a confirmation screen and be asked to restart machine to take effect. Select **OK**

Reboot the system and then reneter the product key either in the GUI or at the command prompt

**slmgr /ipk *product key*** "To enter the product key"

**slmgr /ato** "To activate the Product Key"